# Run Powershell script from URL without temporary file

Tags: powershell

I want to write a PowerShell script that runs a PowerShell script stored at a URL, passing both custom arguments and forwarding any arguments that are given to this PowerShell. Concretely, I can do:

```
$VAR=Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/powershell.ps1
$TEMP=New-TemporaryFile
$FILE=$TEMP.FullName + ".ps1"
$VAR.Content | Out-File $FILE
& $FILE somearguments $args
```

I'd ideally like to do that without using a temporary file, however `powershell -content -` doesn't seem to allow also passing arguments. Is there any way to avoid the temporary file?

Comment: Look how [chocolatey does it](https://chocolatey.org/install)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert content to script block and then invoke it as command with arguments

```
$Script = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://example.com/powershell.ps1'
$ScriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($Script.Content)
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList ($args + @('someargument'))
```

Comment: $args + @('someargument') seems to be required, or it flattens the $args and turns it into a string

Comment: Thanks @NeilMitchell

Answer (score 35):

Stolen straight from chocolatey's site.  I use this more often than i should

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

[source](https://chocolatey.org/install)

Comment: This is what I use, easiest and most direct way.... the `DownloadString()` method pulls the raw contents, then `iex` (`Invoke-Expression`) runs the string that's pulled

Comment: That doesn't seem to permit additional command line arguments to be given to the remote powershell script.

Comment: And will give you this error "This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software."

Answer (score 6):

Automatic download and start `remote` PowerShell script w/0 save (on the fly):

```
iex (iwr $ScriptURL).Content
```

WTF:

[image]

```
alias iex,iwr
```

More help:

```
Get-Help Invoke-Expression
Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest
```

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner will download and source the file from a URL

```
. ([Scriptblock]::Create((([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII).getString((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "${FUNCTIONS_URI}").Content))))
```

example `$FUNCTIONS_URI = "https://github.com/aem-design/aemdesign-docker/releases/latest/download/functions.ps1"`