# Concatenate powershell commands

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'd like to run this commands in 1 line:

```
$url = "https://githubxxxx/install.ps1"
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webClient.Proxy = [System.Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()
$webClient.DownloadString($url) | Invoke-Expression
```

It should be similar to this article:
[Run Powershell script from URL without temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902878/run-powershell-script-from-url-without-temporary-file)

But I have no idea how to put this line:

```
$webClient.Proxy = [System.Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()
```

into this command:

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://githubxxxx/install.ps1'))
```

What I want to achieve run it without proxy from github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iex ((New-Object Net.WebClient -Property @{Proxy = [Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()}).DownloadString('https://githubxxxx/install.ps1'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that is that I want.

Comment: one more new thing come up, I want to run this script from rundeck job, and I need to somehow pass 2 arguments to the command, how can I pass these to my command: "${node.site}" "${node.zone}", I mean how can I define these 2 variables to the command that you've provided? In my script the param already defined.

Answer (score 3):

You can always put statements in same line by separating them with semi-colon `;`:

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;$webClient.Proxy = [System.Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not pretty :D