# Pasteable command to run a batch file from a URL

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, curl

For some internal script distribution, I want to be able to give users a single command they can paste into a Windows cmd window that will run a batch script from a URL.

In bash, the equivalent would be `eval "$(curl -sS https://example.com/my-script)"` or `curl https://example.com/my-script | bash` (but really I do need something more like the former, because I want to set env vars in the existing cmd session).

Similarly, in PowerShell according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68530475/68051 this could be `iex (iwr https://example.com/my-script).Content`.

What's the best equivalent cmd.exe command for doing this?

This is for trusted internal use, so I'm not very worried about security risks of running remote scripts. I'm looking for the quickest easiest command I can give people to paste that will work on a typical Windows machine with no special setup.

Comment: cmd does not have this functionality. You'll need to download curl or use `powershell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://example.com/my-script -OutFile %TEMP%\downloaded.bat && %TEMP%\downloaded.bat
```

It indeed uses powershell to get the file, then it executes it directly in current `cmd`.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. I'd still be interested if anybody has a shorter script or one that doesn't need a temporary file, but this will definitely work.

Comment: @TimPerry You can maybe do something: EACH TIME you face a "new" user, you make him run a (long, ugly) command that will save, in `System32`/`SysWow64`, a helper batch `HelpdeskRun.bat` that takes only an URL as parameter, and do the above trick. It can also delete properly the downloaded file after execution, check URL's domain, keep history, make an automatic elevation, etc. Once this is done, ask your user to simply type `HelpdeskRun [URL]`, and that's it. One micro-setup, then you can enjoy short command lines, and it won't take more than a cluster on user's filesystem.

Comment: @TimPerry Note: the temporary file is required because you switch from Powershell to Batch, and `cmd` isn't always fine when piping a whole batch to its `stdin`... In pure Powershell, you can avoid this easily, but the command line will be even longer than this one.